# What is the variable `C` in some modules in vlib?

Tags: vlang

I was trying to figure out how to use the image library in vlib, in which there was a variable `C`:

```
pub fn (img Image) tex_image_2d() {
    mut rgb_flag := GL_RGB
    if img.ext == 'png' {
        rgb_flag = GL_RGBA
    }
    C.glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, rgb_flag, img.width, 
        img.height, 0, rgb_flag, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.data)
}
```

On the 6th line the function calls a method that belongs to the variable `C`. What kind of object is `C`, and where could I find the source code for it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `C` is not an object, but rather is simply a syntax for instantiating C structs and calling C functions from V code. It's documented [here](https://vlang.io/docs#calling_c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a C function call from imported `#include "stb_image.h"`

[See the code here](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h#L985) for example